# Angular Router: navigateByUrl() resolving with false

Tags: angular, angular-routing

According to Angular's documentation of [`navigateByUrl`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl-anchor), it returns a promise that will resolve with `true` or `false`, depending on whether the navigation succeeded or failed. If an error happens, the promise will be rejected with an error.

I am trying to use `navigateByUrl` within an `AuthGuard` service to navigate the user to their original URL after successful authentication. However, the navigation fails, and the promise is resolved with `false`. It is not rejected. There is no further information on why it fails.

I have verified that the guard returns `true` when triggered via the `navigateToUrl()` call.

Here's the full code for `AuthGuard`:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanLoad, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad {
  public constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
  ) { }
  public canLoad() {
    return this.authService.validateToken()
      .map(isAuthenticated => ({
        isAuthenticated,
        willRedirect: this.manageRedirect(isAuthenticated),
      }))
      .do(result => {
        if (!result.isAuthenticated) {
          // will navigate away from Angular application to OAuth page
          this.authService.startLogin();
        }
      })
      .map(result =>
        result.isAuthenticated && !result.willRedirect);
  }

  private manageRedirect(isAuthenticated: boolean) {
    let willRedirect = false;

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      const redirectUri = sessionStorage.getItem('redirectUri');
      sessionStorage.removeItem('redirectUri');

      if (redirectUri) {
        willRedirect = true;
        this.router.navigateByUrl(redirectUri).then(success => {
          console.log(success);  // false!!
        });
      }
    } else {
      const redirectUri = this.location
        .prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path());

      sessionStorage.setItem('redirectUri', redirectUri);
    }

    return willRedirect;
  }
}
```

Please note that if I delay the `navigateByUrl` call with a timeout of about 1 second, the navigation will work.

Comment: There are too many things that stay behind the scenes. Have you tried to replace a guard with a dummy that returns Observable.of(true)? Considering that you do `navigateByUrl` in the middle of the guard (this smells really bad), the fact that 'guard returns true' means nothing.

Comment: I don't see think calling `navigateByUrl` in the middle of the guard would be a problem. In fact, it's exactly what Angular's official example does: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#teach-authguard-to-authenticate.

Comment: No, it's not. In the tutorial a guard obviously returns false when navigateByUrl is called, which is right thing to do. In yours it's likely not.

Comment: My guard _does_ return `false` in the end, because `willRedirect` is set to `true` at the time of calling `navigateByUrl`, and `.map(result => result.isAuthenticated && !result.willRedirect);` therefore maps to `false`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's not the `canLoad` result that stops the navigation. Something else is interfering.

Comment: There is no evidence that it *stops* the navigation. You said that this results in `false` in `then` callback, which may be totally different thing, because promises are asynchronous and may result in race condition. Currently there's no point in the discussion because it's not totally clear what's going on in the app. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary here. Please, provide a plunk or a fiddle that can replicate the issue.

Comment: There is no asynchronosity between the call to `navigateByUrl` and the return call from the final `map` function that I know results in a `false` value. It's all happening synchronously, and navigation is scheduled for _after_ the end of the guard's execution, so it's easy to verify. That's why I'm saying that this code is no different from the Angular documentation example as far as that part is concerned. I realise it's hard to see these unless there is an actual example to play with, like you've suggested. I will try to create a Plunkr. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Navigation may happen synchronously, but `then` is asynchronous. `.then(success =>` is executed 1 tick later after `canLoad` returns `true`, this is how promises work. Many things could happen during this time. At least that's what I suspect. In Angular example canActivate is synchronous and control flow is clear. In your example it's not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145207/discussion-between-merott-and-estus).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is quite confusing, you're doing to many things at the same time.
You said:

> if I delay the navigateByUrl call with a timeout of about 1 second, the navigation will work.

Javascript is single thread so it will not perform the navigation until it finishes the whole `canLoad` method. So if your logic is dependent on the result from the navigation to proceed on `canLoad` method, you will need to rewrite your logic to run inside the navigation result function `.then(success => { here...`.

Comment: The navigation doesn't actually happen until after the current run of the `AuthGuard` is complete (which return false), and that's what I expect.